# Edittext is not clickable and does not take texts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

[image]

The `EditText` does not seem to take in text. In the sense, I can not click the `EditText` to enter text. It works in my other activities.

This is the java file:

```
public class patientDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText pname; //getting patient name
  String pName; // getting patient name from textbox
  EditText cEm;
  String cEmail;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_details);
    pname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PatientName);
    pName = pname.getText().toString();
    cEm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CGEmail);
    cEmail = cEm.getText().toString();
    phText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayText);
  }
}
```

This is the xml file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/PatientName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="Enter patient's name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/CGEmail"
    android:layout_width="206dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="Enter your email ID"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Contactpicker"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.397"
/>
```

I tried creating another layout file and it does the same thing. I didn't find any errors in the log either.

Comment: Please format your code correct.

Comment: Can you be more concise? I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Someone already took care of it. Ignore it, please.

Comment: Okay. Do you see what's wrong with the code? I need to fix this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Android specialist but you could check if a key listener is set:

```
OnKeyListener listener = new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //Do something
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Another possible problem could be your emulator. Go to the emulator's desktop and try to type in text there (e.g. the app search box) - if it still doesn't work, go to tools/AVD Manager, select your emulator, click Advanced Settings, and check the "enable Keyboard input"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not using an emulator. I use an actual device. I'm able to type into my other layouts which I previously created. It's only this and the new ones that I'm trying to create. I will try the key listener.